# Reducing the strength of a category theoretic proof

Tags: logic, reference-request, set-theory, proof-theory, reverse-math

The motivation for this question is the following: Say we have a formula $\phi$ in peano arithmetic, and we have proof $\pi$ of $\phi$ using possibly higher order arithmetic or category theory (that is the proof assumes larger [proof-theoretic ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_analysis)). It is often the case that the inaccessible cardinal required to do category theory is completely overkill for the result, as the proof does not actually do any complicated induction. For a precise example, [FLT](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293005/what-is-known-about-the-relationship-between-fermats-last-theorem-and-peano-ari) depends on category theory yet is believed to have a proof in PA.

I would like to know if there are any results pertaining to the following question: Is there a general (semi)-decision procedure which, given a formula $\phi$ in a given system of strength $\alpha$, analyzes a proof $\pi$ in a system of strength $\beta>\alpha$ and outputs a more elementary proof of $\phi$ if such a proof exists, possibly under certain constraints?

Comment: Just a side note,  but category theory, as such, doesn't require inaccessible cardinals. Such cardinals, when they give you a Grothendieck universe, are useful, but whether they're necessary depends very much on the application.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Yes, but in just about any use of categories one would consider the category X for X a class of objects, or at the very least would require the category of sets to talk about presheaves.

Comment: You can do many perfectly serviceable things with large categories without assuming a bigger universe in which they're sets. It's not the case that if we don't have a universe then we can't talk about the category of sets, or about presheaves on a small category. I'm guessing you maybe have specific category theoretic arguments in mind, but the phrase "the inaccessible cardinal required by category theory" was strange enough that I had to comment.